# Bibliography does not print and /cite command does not work but shows no errors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

```
% Makes header
\pagestyle{fancy}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\fancyhead[R]{\textit{Final Year Project Proposal, 2024}}

\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Student Name, student ID}}

% Makes footnotes with an asterisk

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{center}


\Large{\textbf{Proposed Project Title (group)}}\\


\vspace{0.4cm}

\normalsize

Project Topic (general area), e.g. “Solar Energy”, “Photonic Devices”, and “RF IC Design” \\

\vspace{0.1cm}

\textit{Supervisor:}

\small{Prof. X}\\

\vspace{0.1cm}

\textit{Project Subtitle:}

\small{Subtitle specific to given team member}

\medskip

\normalsize

\end{center}

{\color{gray}\hrule}

\vspace{0.4cm}

\begin{abstract}

\input{./abstract.tex}

\end{abstract}

{\color{gray}\hrule}

\medskip

\input{./document.tex}





\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{references}
```

The only thing that this prints is the References title and below is my .bib file.

```
@article{Bowker1985,

  doi = {10.2307/2617706},

  url = {https://doi.org/10.2307/2617706},

  year = {1985},

  publisher = {Oxford University Press ({OUP})},

  volume = {61},

  number = {4},

  pages = {607--618},

  author = {Mike Bowker and Phil Williams},

  title = {Helsinki and West European Security},

  journal = {International Affairs}

}
```

Overleaf isn't giving me any errors when compiling so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. The latex file was provided to me to write a report and I'm not supposed to change anything but I can't cite anything so I'm lost on what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! We are going to be of limited assistance unless you can provide us with code which reproduces the problem. Right now, nobody but you can do that because we don't have anything we can compile. However, are those blank lines a result of copy-paste or are they in your source? Because I doubt BibTeX likes them. So I would begin by removing them from the bibliography entry.

Comment: Off-topic: `\Large` doesn't take an argument. If your supervisor set this up, by all means follow her/his/their guidance concerning your project, but don't listen to any advice she/he/they give you about (La)TeX! This is virtually all non-semantic markup and not very good non-semantic markup at that. It looks very much like the code I get from automatic conversions of Word forms.